# React image element referenced

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am converting an application over from jquery to react and I have a [Kjua](https://larsjung.de/kjua/) QR code component that I'm working on. My previous code creates the Kjua element in javascript

```
const qrcode = kjua({
    text: target_url,
    render: 'svg',
    size: 200,
    mode: 'image',
    ecLevel: 'Q',
    mSize: 25,
    quiet: 2,
    image: document.getElementById("logo"),
});
```

This references a `'logo'` image in the DOM that references an SVG.

converting this over to react, I found the [Kjua-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-kjua) wrapper to use the library within react.  Setting this up without the image overlay works fine:

```
function QRCode() {
    const target_url = 'something';
    return <Kjua text={target_url} render="svg" size="200" ecLevel="Q" mSize="25" quiet="2"/>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<QRCode />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

But I'm not sure how to reference the logo within react, and introducing the image overlay like the following:

```
function QRCode() {
    const target_url = 'something';
    return <Kjua text={target_url} render="svg" size="200" ecLevel="Q" mSize="25" quiet="2" mode="image" image="document.getElementById('logo')"/>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<QRCode />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Gives the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.getAttribute is not a function
The above error occurred in the <Kjua> component
Uncaught TypeError: t.getAttribute is not a function
```

How do you render the image or create an `HTMLImageElement` and reference that within a react component?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use a [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Comment: I tried a few different approaches using ref, would you show me how @yainspan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways:

**The first**. Pass image node through the props to target component

```
function QRCode({image}) {
    const target_url = 'something';
    return <Kjua text={target_url} render="svg" size="200" ecLevel="Q" mSize="25" quiet="2" mode="image" image={image}/>;
}

const image = document.getElementById('logo')
ReactDOM.render(<QRCode image={image}/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**The second**. Because sometimes it's not so trivial to pass a props you can just get reference to image node inside react component itself

```
function QRCode() {
    const target_url = 'something';
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        setImage(document.getElementById('logo'))
    }, [])
    return image ? <Kjua text={target_url} render="svg" size="200" ecLevel="Q" mSize="25" quiet="2" mode="image" image={image}/> : null;
}

ReactDOM.render(<QRCode/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**The third**. If you are sure that when you render an element you have access to DOM you can replace `useEffect` on `useMemo` to get image synchronously

```
function QRCode() {
    const target_url = 'something';
    const image = useMemo(() => document.getElementById('logo'), [])
    return <Kjua text={target_url} render="svg" size="200" ecLevel="Q" mSize="25" quiet="2" mode="image" image={image}/>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<QRCode/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

P.s. The problem in your code that you pass to `image` prop string and kjua code behind react Kjua expect that image would be a DOM Element, so this is why you get exception.

Comment: Ah, very good, this works.  I ended up using something along the lines of #2.  Thanks @maksimr!